# Pandas crosstab, but with values from aggregation of third column

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

Here is my problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'one'] ,
                   'B': ['Ar', 'Br', 'Cr', 'Ar','Ar'] ,
                   'C': [1, 0, 0, 1,0 ]})
```

I would like to generate something like output of `pd.crosstab` function, but values on the intersection of column and row should come from aggregation of third column:

```
    Ar,  Br, Cr
one 0.5 0  0
two 1  0  0
```

For example, there are two cases of 'one' and 'Ar' corresponding values in column 'C' are 1,0 we sum up values in column 'C' (0+1) and divide by number of values   in column 'C', so we get (0+1)/2 =0.5. Whenever combination is not present we (like 'Cr' and 'one') we set it to zero. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like `groupby` and `unstack`

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).C.mean().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

you can use [pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) method, which uses `aggfunc='mean'` per-default:

```
In [46]: df.pivot_table(index='A', columns='B', values='C', fill_value=0)
Out[46]:
B     Ar  Br  Cr
A
one  0.5   0   0
two  1.0   0   0
```

Comment: Both you and piRSquared provided excellent answers! They are both correct answers, it is hard to decide whom to give the official answer label. I gave it to piRSquared since he/she has slightly lower rank than yours. I hope you do not mind.

Comment: @user1700890, it's absolutely fine! I really like his answer too. Actually `pivot_table()` does exactly that (plus some additional stuff) under the hood... ;)